# Widget for Sitewide Editable Content?

Tags: plugins, theme-development, themes, widgets, text

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add New Footer Widget Area with Limited Options?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76943/add-new-footer-widget-area-with-limited-options)

I have a banner and a footer that I need to be editable, but I'm not sure if a widget is the best way to accomplish this.  It's going to be basic text or an unordered list. As an example I included some code below:

```
<ul>
<li>line one</li>
<li>line two</li>
<li>line three</li>
</ul>
```

How would I be able to edit the text "line one" "line two" and "line three" so that it's editable and it will change across the whole website?

Comment: Something like [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76943/add-new-footer-widget-area-with-limited-options/76949#76949)?

Comment: @toscho thanks! that seems like what I'm looking for! could you add it as an answer so I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: I don’t want to get rep for the same content twice. :)